# How do I pass the correct parameters to the 'az storage fs upload' command?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cli

How do I use 'az storage fs upload' ?    There appears to be 3 basic arguments but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-directory-upload) does not clearly explain exactly what they are.

The old style of this command looked like this, and it worked.  I was getting WARNING messages ( *WARNING: This command is implicitly deprecated because command group 'storage blob directory' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use 'az storage fs directory' instead.* ) telling to to migrate to a new command style:

```
az storage blob directory upload -c '$web' --account-name $STACCT --recursive \
 -s /agent/_work/1/service-name/karate/target/cucumber-html-reports 
 -d TESTS/2022/2022-08-05/16:38:07/dev/service-name --account-key $STKEY
```

And I am trying to get it to work this way, as the warning message suggested, but it says my syntax is wrong:

```
 az storage fs directory upload -f '$web' --account-name $STACCT \
  -s /agent/_work/1/service-name/karate/target/cucumber-html-reports \
  -p TESTS/2022-08-05/16:38:07/dev/service-name --account-key $STKEY
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: -p TESTS/2022-08-05/16:38:07/dev/service-name/...
```

If I pass `-d` instead of `-p`, it just hangs and says nothing.

So, is there any real documentation on exactly what these parameters are supposed to look like?

Comment: Have you tried [setting up permission for file/directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/29767d75d850ddc1c24cc85bd46d861b61d77a47/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/storage/docs/ADLS%20Gen2.md#set-permissions-of-a-path)? References: [--permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-directory-create-required-parameters) and [Levels of permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#levels-of-permission)

Comment: [Upload a file with specific permissions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/29767d75d850ddc1c24cc85bd46d861b61d77a47/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/storage/docs/ADLS%20Gen2.md#set-permissions-of-a-path:~:text=Upload%20a%20file%20with%20specific%20permissions%20to%20ADLS%20Gen2%20file%20system)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using az interactive to test the new command and available parameters, the autocompletion could be handy.
You can use Azure CLI in interactive mode by running the `az interactive` command.
The Azure CLI interactive mode places you in an interactive shell with auto-completion, command descriptions, and examples.
Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/interactive-azure-cli